# qemu - bridge VM's to VM's in Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, qemu, kvm, bridge

I am a qemu complete novice. I have a Dell 720 with CentOS 7 running qemu.  It can reach the Internet, as well as bridge to all the VM's running.

On my laptop I run VirtualBox with a Debian 10 VM that I do dev on and I'd like to connect to the VM's running via qemu.  How do I  bridge these two networks so they can talk back and forth? The VirtualBox VM are 10.0.0.X and the qemu VMs are 192.168.222.X.

TIA.

Comment: The easiest way, probably, is to use bridged adapters. In the VirtualBox UI, it's as easy as changing the "Atached to:" drop down selection. For `qemu` check: https://medium.com/@kartik.joshi7889/simplest-way-set-up-bridge-networking-in-kvm-qemu-and-vmm-bf96c134f445

Comment: You need a virtual switch. 
look in to openvswitch